# NHibernate session lifetime management

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I guess, it's a common question for everyone, who meets NHibernate in ASP.NET applications, but even after two hours of googling I still can't figure out, how to manage ISession lifetime properly.
I got that it is supposed to be one ISession instance per request, but problem is that my ISessionFactory is injected deep down in call stack in repositories in infrastructure layer, which is called by domain classes and only after that by controllers. I'd like my domain services to remain singletons to prevent their recreation each request, but I can't inject request-dependent services into singleton services. On the other hand, I can't open and close sessions manually at repositories, because I lose "laziness" this way.
So, the question is, how to register ISession in IOC-container, to get it new each request but to use it from singleton repositories?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the session when you start the request, and bind to the request context (which would be the request in your case - make sure to configure current session context),

```
session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
```

and then within the repositories you can use the sesssionFactory to get the current session

```
session = this.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```